# Swift Google+ login GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().userID equals always nil

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, google-signin

I'm trying to implement Google+ login in iOS app using Swift language.

My code looks like this:

```
var kClientId = "My Client ID from Dev Console"
var signIn = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance()
signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = true
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = true
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserID = true
signIn.clientID = kClientId
signIn.scopes = [kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin]
signIn.delegate = self
signIn.authenticate()
```

For test purposes I created a lable and wanted to change this to user email who logged in.

```
if (GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().userID != nil) {
    var user = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().googlePlusUser
    userName.text = user.name.JSONString()
    if (user.emails != nil){
        userEmailLable.text = user.emails.first?.JSONString() ?? "no email"
    } else {
        userEmailLable.text = "no email"
    }
} else {
    println("User ID is nil")
}
```

After I click "Login" button Safari tab opens and I can enter my Google email and password and it asks permissions for certain things and after pressing Accept button it returns back to the application. My userEmailLable is not changed and it prints "User ID is nil" as an output. It happens all the time and there were not a single successful login.

My Google frameworks are all fine, URLs are also correct, in Google Developer console are everything as it should be.

AppDelegate.swift file includes this function also

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourcApplication: String, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return GPPURLHandler.handleURL(url, sourceApplication: sourcApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Anybody knows why is it doing so? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is strange. I tried out building an example following the [Google instructions.](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in) It works as expected and prints out the right output.

Also, [here is another nice step-by-step writeup.](https://medium.com/swift-programming/google-in-swift-a0943352dfe9)

I did the same steps as specified by the guide - create a console app, register URL scheme for the iOS app using my bundle ID.

Here’s my view controller code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, GPPSignInDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let signIn = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance()
        signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = true
        signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = true  // Uncomment to get the user's email
        signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserID = true

        signIn.clientID = "… my client ID"

        // Uncomment one of these two statements for the scope you chose in the previous step
        signIn.scopes = [ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ]  // "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" scope

        signIn.delegate = self
        signIn.authenticate()
    }



    // MARK: - GPPSignInDelegate

    func finishedWithAuth(auth: GTMOAuth2Authentication!, error: NSError!) {
        print("received auth \(auth), error \(error)")

        if (GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().userID != nil) {
            let user = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().googlePlusUser
            println("user name: " + user.name.JSONString() + "\nemail: ")
            if (user.emails != nil){
                print(user.emails.first?.JSONString() ?? "no email")
            } else {
                print("no email")
            }
        } else {
            println("User ID is nil")
        }
    }
}
```

In addition to this, I have the app delegate function also (but note that some of the optional specifiers are different)

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return GPPURLHandler.handleURL(url, sourceApplication:sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Comment: I am getting Invalid redeclaration error in AppDelegate...Please if you could help me..I am learning swift ad-hoc so I am finding it difficult